# Finding first element of list returned by dict.get

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict whose values are all lists, and I need to extract the first element of the list for a given key.

I had been using

```
var = varDict.get(key, 0)
```

But now that the value is a list I need the same var which was the value and is now the first element of the list.

I've tried a few variations, mostly involving putting square brackets in different places with varying numbers in them, my attempt's at slice notation and pulling it from the list the standard way, all of which resulted in either dict.get returning default everytime, or nothing.

From researching, it seems like this isn't an issue people have really run into, I tried some of the answers to similar problems but none of them work with this combination of elements.

I could also do this by adding an `if` statement and expanding this quite a bit, but as long as there is a built-in way to do this, which I would assume there is, I'd prefer to keep the code as neat and minimal as practical.

---

#### Some Context

In this particular situation a fuller snippet of my code is:

```
varDict[key] = [vardict.get(key, 0) + step,item2,item3]
```

As you can likely see here, my goal is to increment (or decrement depending on value of step) the `int` in the list/value associated with the key, overwriting the other two values of the list, and creating the key if it it doesn't already exist.

---

#### Some Examples

**As moondra requested here are some examples of expected output:**

Starting with `varDict` as an empty dict:

```
key = "test", step = 1, item2 = True, item3 = False
```

Should result in:

```
varDict = {"test": [1, True, False]}
```

Then:

```
key = "test", step = 1, item2 = False, item3 = False
```

Results in:

```
varDict = {"test": [2, False, False]}
```

Then:

```
key = "words", step = -1, item2 = False, item3 = False
```

Results in:

```
varDict = {"test": [2, False, False], "words": [-1, False, False]}
```

---

I would like to note however that I'm looking for an answer to my question, not my situation, as answering my question could be of help to others who find this and have the same question, whereas my situation is pretty specific to me, now. An answer to the question should help me solve my situation. I think because I'm a low rep user people have assumed I just want my problem solved (as per the vampire comments in some recent meta posts), but I'm only low rep because I'm not experienced enough to answer other peoples questions and most of my questions have already been answered, effectively limiting ways for me to earn rep, I've been around this community for a good few years and know how it works, I just haven't been able to give back the way I'd like to. I by no means intend to leech from this community and I'm going to cut myself short here because what was supposed to just be "answer the question, don't solve my situation" has already expanded into something that will likely have the question closed as off-topic or not actually a question but just a rant, but hopefully atleast a few people will take note of it first. **Edit:** I also find it interesting that this has happened at the same time as [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371796/if-stack-overflow-is-about-building-a-qa-library-how-to-communicate-and-uphol?cb=1). Which would be a far better place for me to put this, and I would have moved it there with a note about the coincidence that I also just finally gained enough rep to earn the privelege "Participate in meta", however in the time it took me to read that meta post, I lost two rep putting me under the level required to participate, so here I am once again adding irrelevant information to the wrong place because even now that there's already a post that would be perfect for me to add to, I'm still excluded.

Comment: "I have a dict whose values are all lists" - then what do you mean that your goal is to increment the `int` value associated with the key? Could you give a sample value?

Comment: If your values are all lists, `varDict.get(key, 0)` is a very bad idea—that means you get back a list if the key is found, but the number 0 if it isn't. And there aren't many things you can usefully do with `var` if it's either a list or a number but you don't know which. You probably wanted something like `varDict.get(key, [])` or `varDict.get(key, [0])` or something, but without knowing what you're trying to do with `var` it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: As a wild guess, you may be looking for `varDict[key] = [varDict.get(key, [0])[0] + tep, item2, item3]`? In other words: if the key is found, you want the first element of the value; if not, you want the first element of `[0]` (that is, `0`). That's a clunky way to write that, but it works.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm referring the the int within the list which is the value of the key, I thought that was fairly clear, but I did some last minute editing to the top of the question before posting which may have obscured that, I'll see if I can edit that to be a little clearer.

Comment: @abarnert ~another victim of my last minute editing before I posted, I changed some of the wording surrounding the snippet without checking the snippet made sense still.~Edit: No upon further inspection that should be explained by the next sentence. "But now that the value is a list..."

Comment: I still don't understand: "But now that the value is a list I need the same var which was the value and is now the first element of the list." What does that mean? If you have a dict whose values are lists, then `var` is going to be a list if the key is found, but the number 0 if it isn't. Just as I said the first time.

Comment: @abarnert It's stating that was the code, before the values were lists, but now they are lists, the problem is occuring.

Comment: You should add some concrete examples (small examples) and the expected result as it's really confusing as to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a new dictionary where the values are the first value of the list of a dictionary of lists, you can use a comprehension.

```
{key:lst[0] for key, lst in dct.items()}
```

This loops over the items in the dictionary, and creates a new dictionary with the same keys where the associated value is the first element in the original dictionaries' lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem:

You have some code that does stuff with the first element of a list:

```
[var[0] + step, item2, item3]
```

… and you have those lists in a dict, so you can do this:

```
var = varDict[key]
[var[0] + step, item2, item3]
```

… but some of the keys are missing, so you need a default value, so you did this:

```
var = varDict.get(key, 0)
```

… but that doesn't work, because `0` obviously doesn't have a first element. What you need is something that *does* have a first element, and that first element should be 0.

That's just a list with 0 in it:

```
var = varDict.get(key, [0])
```

That's it.

---

Putting it all together, I think the line you may be trying to write is:

```
varDict[key] = [varDict.get(key, [0])[0], item2, item3]
```

However, I think it's probably more readable to leave it as two lines:

```
var = varDict.get(key, [0])
varDict[key] = [var[0], item2, item3]
```

… or maybe you actually wanted `varDict` to be a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

varDict = defaultdict(lambda: [0])
# ...
varDict[key][:] = [varDict[key][0]+step, item2, item3]
```

Comment: Stop focusing on the lack of square brackets around the `0` I already explained in the comments of the question that the snippet you're referring to was from before the values became lists containing the int I want, I am fully aware that the `int` alone is not a list.

Comment: As for the other changes, they appear to sum up to appending [0] to the end of dict.get() which is something I had already tried (as per  "I've tried a few variations, mostly involving putting square brackets in different places with varying numbers in them" though I'll admit that's hardly clear). If I remember correctly that just left me with a blank dict in the end.